# Class List Keeps Printing Out As Class Name In Console?

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

Ok, so maybe I'm just tired or something but I can't seem to figure out why this keeps happening.

The code below is called every day for a data point in a database I have.

When I print to the console for debugging, it simply prints out as:

```
NamespaceName.SharePrices
```

Not sure what is going on.

```
       public void OnData(TradeBars data)
       {
        decimal price = data["IBM"].Price;
        DateTime today = data["IBM"].Time;
        //--------------Below works fine.
        if (today.Date >= nextTradeDate.Date)
        {
            MarketOnOpenOrder("IBM", 50);
            Debug("Purchased Stock");
            nextTradeDate = today.AddDays(1);
            MarketOnOpenOrder("IBM", -25);
        }
        var derpList = new SharePrices { theDate = today, sharePrice = price };
        List<SharePrices> newList = new List<SharePrices>();
        newList.Add(derpList);
        newList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}

public class SharePrices
{
    public DateTime theDate { get; set; }
    public decimal sharePrice { get; set; }
}
```

Please excuse my naming conventions.  This is just a wireframe for a personal project.

//----------Edit

Thanks for the help guys.  I guess what I wasn't understanding is why it was working in my TestClass I wrote just playing with fake data, and when the real implementation came it didn't work:

```
        public static void FindWindowDays()
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();
        for (var dt = currentDate.AddDays(-windowDays); dt <= currentDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
            dates.Add(dt);
        }
        var ascending = dates.OrderByDescending(i => i);
        foreach (var datesyo in ascending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(datesyo);
        }
    }
```

This seemed to work fine printing the DateTime to console without converting to string. But when I added the second element, it stopped working.  That's where I got confuddled.

Comment: If you want it to display something more specific, you will have to override `ToString()`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what part of [Object.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is confusing for you? "Default implementations of the `Object.ToString` method return the fully qualified name of the object's type"... Or maybe [WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) does not mention "the ToString method of value is called to produce its string representation"?

Comment: It was confusing, because in my TestClass I wrote with dummy data it printed to console just fine, using DateTime and Decimal.  I don't usually debug in console.

Comment: The reason why it worked in your dummy class is because the built-in `DateTime` class has its own `ToString()` method. Your custom class does not, so C# defaults to the `NamespaceName.ClassName` if nothing is specified.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why writing items to console writes only namespace and class name instead of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284706/why-writing-items-to-console-writes-only-namespace-and-class-name-instead-of-dat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `ToString()` for your class in format as you want, for example like this:

```
public class SharePrices
{
    public DateTime theDate { get; set; }
    public decimal sharePrice { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("The Date: {0}; Share Price: {1};", theDate, sharePrice);
    }
}
```

By default, without overriding,  `ToString()` returns a string that represents the current object. So that's why you get what you described.

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't know anything about the `SharePrices` other than the class name. If you want it to display something specific, you will need to override the `ToString()` method like so:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "SharePrice: " + theDate.ToString() + ": " + sharePrice.ToString();
}
```

Of course, you can format it however you like, that is the beauty of it. If you only care about the price and not the date, only `return` the `sharePrice`.

Comment: Hrm, I see what you are saying.  Can anyone think of a way to do this without converting to a string in the SharePrices class?  I need to use the data later on down the line in another class.

Comment: @J.Rewo, your data will not be changed. When you call .ToString() you will get just new string obj, without change state of your class.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Console.WriteLine` on a class, it will call the `ToString()` method on that class automatically.

If you want to print the details out, you will over need to override `ToString()` in your class, or call `Console.WriteLine` with each property you want to print out.

Answer (score 0):

this will work without having to use `.ToString()`

```
public class SharePrices
{
    public DateTime theDate { get; set; }
    public decimal sharePrice { get; set; }
}

SharePrices sp = new SharePrices() { theDate = DateTime.Now, sharePrice = 10 };

var newList2 = new List<SharePrices>();
newList2.Add(sp);
newList2.ForEach(itemX => Console.WriteLine("Date: {0} Sharprice: {1}",sp.theDate, sp.sharePrice));
```

Comment: I think foreach is waiting for Action<SharePrice>, but you pass Action<string>, so that's why you get compile error. Am I wrong?

Comment: this compiles just fine not sure what you are talking about also perhaps you're not use to seeing this type of looping through a `List<T>` object load up a List with some string and try it out

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PlXwFe , I'm talking about that. Take a look on question, he is looping through List<T>.