# Why writing items to console writes only namespace and class name instead of data?

Tags: c#

Probably the title doesn't sound very well for most of you guys (skilled programmers), but I'm on my 3rd week of learning C# fundamentals and I cant figure it out how to solve the next task.
I shall store some temperatures for a bunch of cities, asking a user for a cityName first and then for the actual temp in that city. All this stuff should be saved in a list<> and I shall use Class and Constructor.
When I try to print out the result (using foreach) it prints out the name of my namespace and the name of my class like "Task_5.City"
Whats wrong with my code:

```
public class City //class
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int Temperature { get; set; }

    public City(string name, int temp)//konstruktor 
    {
        this.CityName = name;
        this.Temperature = temp;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cityList = new List<City>(); 

        Console.WriteLine("What is your city?");
        string cityName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What temperature for this city?");
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        City myCity = new City(cityName, temp);
        cityList.Add(myCity);


        foreach (var item in cityList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing object to the `Console.WriteLine(item)` instead of passing the string. `Console.WriteLine` invokes `ToString()` method of that object that by default returns namespace+class name. You can override this behavior like next:

```
    public class City //class
    {
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public int Temperature { get; set; }

        public City(string name, int temp)//konstruktor 
        {
            this.CityName = name;
            this.Temperature = temp;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", CityName, Temperature);
        }

    }
```

Or you can use another overload of `WriteLine` method:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.CityName, item.Temperature);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `Console.WriteLine(item);` to one of the following options, if you simply want to write out the contents of your `City` object.

```
Console.WriteLine("City: " + item.CityName + " has a temperature of " + item.Temperature + " degrees.");
```

or, you can use `string.Format` if you prefer:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("City: {0} has a temperature of {1} degrees.", item.CityName, item.Temperature));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using this overload of `WriteLine`:

```
public static void WriteLine(object value)
```

and this overload call `ToString` method of parameter to produce its string representation. As mentioned [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx#Default) the default implementation of `ToString` returns the fully qualified name of the type.

You can override `ToString` in your `City` class to be able use instances of this type where a string is expected like `Console.WriteLine`

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return CityName + Temperature.ToString(); 
   // return $"{CityName} : {Temperature}"; // Or use C# string interpolation
}
```

Or directly produce required string and pass that to `WriteLine` method:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{item.CityName} : {item.Temperature});
```

Answer (score 2):

The item in cityList is of City type, which means that you have properties for CityName and Temperature.

You should use:

`Console.WriteLine(item.CityName + " is at " + item.Temperature + ".");`

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to print the object itself. If you would like to print the CityName and Temperature, inside the foreach you have to print the property.

```
foreach (var item in cityList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.CityName);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Temperature);
    }
```

But here, you are getting a single city and temperature only and printing it. Why do you need a list in that case?

Comment: `But here, you are getting a single city and temperature only and printing it. Why do you need a list in that case?` - That's totally irrelevant, but let me help in answering: because that code is either clearly work-in-progress  or it was trimmed down to make it smaller. It's quite easy to add a second City to that list and it would still not work as intended. Also, OP clearly said that he will store a "bunch of cities" there, so, well, a List, surprise!

Comment: Yes, @quetzalcoatl you should be right. This might be a work-in-progess. I see there is something missing in the code than in the description. Just wanted to fill in the gaps.It was a good intention! :)

Comment: @AnjuRaj Why do you need a list in that case?
Well, because so far I've learned arrays and lists, and this task doesn't soppose me to use anything that I haven't learned yet. What would you use instead? Maybe single variables, one for the Temp and one for the City?