# Trying to print values in list is giving me "Project.Game"

Tags: c#

So I created this list which seems to be created fine:

```
        List<Game> JoinLists = new List<Game>();
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Elf", 6));
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Angel", 10));
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Demon", 10));
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Wizard", 9));
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Undead", 7));
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Vampire", 9));
        JoinLists.Add(new Game("Troll", 6));
```

Now I am trying to access it using:

```
            Console.WriteLine("This is the list of characters you can choose from:");
            foreach(var character in JoinLists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(character);
            }
```

Can anyone explain why the items being printed are "Project.Game"?  I also have these stored in Game.cs:

```
    private string _type;
    private int _strength;

    public Game(string charType, int strength)
    {
        this._type = charType;
        this._strength = strength;
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Why writing items to console writes only namespace and class name instead of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284706/why-writing-items-to-console-writes-only-namespace-and-class-name-instead-of-dat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement a `ToString()` method in `Game` class, like that

```cs
private string _type;
private int _strength;

public Game(string charType, int strength)
{
    this._type = charType;
    this._strength = strength;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{_type} {_strength}";
}
```

By default `Console.Writeline` uses `ToString()` method of an object, which returns type of object, when it [isn't overridden](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,ff31a6bf27c58f89,references), `Project.Game` in your case

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(character);
```

This line implicitly calls `character.ToString();` which you haven't defined. Since you didn't override the default implementation, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8), the result is to simply return the fully qualified type name (in this case, `"Project.Game"`).

If you want a specific output, either override the `ToString()` method of `Game`, create a new method dedicated to printable output, or, instead of just trying to `WriteLine(character)` directly, try logging some specific properties of the character (I would give an example but all of your properties are private and thus couldn't be accessed this way as-is).

Overriding `ToString()` would look like this:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return $"{_type} (str: {_strength})";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine` calls the object's `ToString()` method in order to turn the object into a string.  Your `Game` class doesn't have such a method, so its base class's implementation is used.  `object.ToString()` has a default implementation that simply spits out the name of the class.

If you want your `Game` class to actually show some info on the console, you have two options.

First, implement `ToString()` in your class.  As an example:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return _type;
}
```

Secondly, write out individual properties to the console as desired:

```
Console.WriteLine(character.Type);
```

Note that for the second option to *be an option*, you need to implement some public properties.  Right now you have a pair of private fields.