# Cannot write the correct value on Json file

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, postman

I'm trying to write a function that wirte on my Json file the value I enter on PostMan
I have my Json file as following:

```
[
    {
        "targets":[
            "192.168.1.101:9182",
            "192.168.1.103:9100",
            "192.168.1.105:9182"
        ]
    }
]
```

M tried to for example a target with the following query:

```
{
        "targets": [
            "192.168.1.117:9100"
        ]
}
```

Here is my class model:

```
public class targetResponse
    {
        public IList<string> targets { get; set; }
    }
```

using postman as shown in the picture:
[image]

Everything works fine in the part of prometheus (gives me no error).

Here is the function that I use:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(targetResponse), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<targetResponse>> PostNewInstanceToConfig([FromBody] targetResponse _target)
{
    IList<targetResponse> myList = new List<targetResponse>();
    var jsonString = System.IO.File
       .ReadAllText(_filePath);
    myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetResponse>>(jsonString);
    myList.FirstOrDefault().targets.Add(_target.ToString());
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(_filePath);
    JsonSerializer mySerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myList);
    myWriter.Close();

    return null;
}
```

It opens the file and write following thing, I dont understand why it doesnt why:

```
[
  {
    "targets": [
      "192.168.1.101:9182",
      "192.168.1.103:9100",
      "192.168.1.105:9182",
      "ApplicationTestCRUD_JSON.targetResponse",
      "ApplicationTestCRUD_JSON.targetResponse"
    ]
  }
]
```

The "ApplicationTestCRUD_JSON" is the name of my project.

Any help please?

**EDIT:**

I added a `foreach` loop and removed `.toString()` method, my function now looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(targetResponse), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<targetResponse>> PostNewInstanceToConfig([FromBody] targetResponse _target)
{
    IList<targetResponse> myList = new List<targetResponse>();
    var jsonString = System.IO.File
       .ReadAllText(_filePath);
    myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetResponse>>(jsonString);
    foreach(var x in _target.targets)
    {
        myList.FirstOrDefault().targets.Add(x);
    }
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(_filePath);
    JsonSerializer mySerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myList);
    myWriter.Close();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816246/class-list-keeps-printing-out-as-class-name-in-console/33816284)

Comment: Can you share the code of class targetResponse?

Comment: Yes ofc check the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `_target.ToString()` and since `_target` is of type `targetResponse` you get the default ToString text back, which is the full name of the object type.

You probably want to access a property of `_target` instead.

Comment: I can't the `_target ` directelly it gives me compilation error :/

Comment: Yes, because `targetResponse.targets` is probably a `List<string>` so you need to either add a property of `_target` (like `_target.Address` or something?)

Comment: No it doesnt have any propriety, I added the model in the post bellow

Comment: Then maybe you are trying to add all `_target.targets` to the list of `myList.FirstOrDefault().targets`? Then you could use `myList.FirstOrDefault().targets.AddRange(_target.targets)`.

Comment: Sorry, seems that `IList<T>` doesn't support `AddRange`, so you probably want to use a foreach loop to add each element of `_target.targets` to `myList.FirstOrDefault().targets` one by one.