# C# SQL records from table to list

Tags: c#, list, console

I'm trying to get all records from table and print them out in console.

My Userlist.cs

```
public List<Userlist> CreateList()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Sqlstring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ListCreateQuery, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<Userlist> Users = new List<Userlist>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Userlist U = new Userlist();
                    U.fornavn = (string)reader["Fornavn"];
                    U.efternavn = (string)reader["Efternavn"];
                    U.mail = (string)reader["Mail"];
                    U.tlfnr = (string)reader["TlfNr"];

                    Users.Add(U);
                }

                return Users;
            }
        }              
    }
}
```

And I try to print it out from my main (Or a method is fine)

```
if (UserAnswer == "1")
{
    Console.Clear();

    Userlist UL = new Userlist();

    foreach (Userlist user in UL.CreateList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run it, it only prints `mynamespace.userlist` 3 times over (my number of records)

Comment: Because its your class. Either override the `ToString` of that class and or select a property of the class... for axample: `Console.WriteLine(user.fornavn);`

Comment: Im new to List so its most trial and error, how would i change it so it would print out whats in the list?

Comment: Ahh thank u Codexer, that fixed my problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class List Keeps Printing Out As Class Name In Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816246/class-list-keeps-printing-out-as-class-name-in-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a class object into `Console.WriteLine` will invoke it's `.ToString()` method if the object is not `null`. If you want the property values to be displayed when calling `.ToString()` you can `override` the method in your class:

```
public class Userlist
{
    .....

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "fornavn: " + fornavn + " efternavn: " + efternavn + " mail: " + mail 
                       + " tlfnr: " + tlfnr;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is acutally what im trying to do, how would i implement this? Never worked with override before.

Comment: Just add what I have in my answer to your `class` `Userlist`. It will then call this version of `.ToString()` when you pass the object into `Console.WriteLine`. If you want to read more about it, here's a link to the MSDN docs: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you for the help and for the read :))

Comment: `Passing a class object into Console.WriteLine will invoke it's .ToString() method if the object is not null` maybe `Passing an object...` anything inside that method will call `ToString`. Of course you mentioned if its not null it cant call that method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using toString on the object so it prints the objects name

You need to use it on each property and write:

```
            foreach(Userlist user in UL.CreateList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user.fornavn);
                Console.WriteLine(user.efternavn );
                Console.WriteLine(user.mail);
                Console.WriteLine(user.tlfnr);
            }
```